# LAS Tools Isn´t Working: No new Shapefile Generated

Tags: qgis, lastools

I´m Currently working with QGIS version is 3.30  and the latest aviable version of LasTools
I simply want to create a Hillshaded Ground only digital model
Thus, I´m using blast2dem for a whole folder
My LiDAR is sourced from the Spanish IGN, the latest version aviable

The problem is, blast2dem says it generated a whole new TIFF...and nothing new is generated
In the end I´m left with 0 new shapes, neither in my QGIS project, neither in the folder where I specify it should be...while the process says there should be a shape here

The log output of blast2dem looks like this:

Algoritmo 'blast2dem (file)' comenzando…

Parámetros de entrada:

{ 'ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS' : '', 'ATTRIBUTE' : 0, 'FILTER_RETURN_CLASS_FLAGS1' : 7, 'GUI' : False, 'INPUT_LASLAZ' : 'E:\DOUTORADO\AnllonsLidar\PNOA_2015_GAL-W_498-4786_ORT-CLA-CIR.las', 'OUTPUT_RASTER' : 'E:/DOUTORADO/ProbaLasA.tiff', 'PRODUCT' : 1, 'STEP' : 1, 'USE_TILE_BB' : False, 'VERBOSE' : False }

LAStools command line

C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Doutorado/LAStools\bin\blast2dem -i "E:\DOUTORADO\AnllonsLidar\PNOA_2015_GAL-W_498-4786_ORT-CLA-CIR.las" -keep_class 2 -step 1.0 -hillshade -o "E:/DOUTORADO/ProbaLasA.tiff"

LAStools console output

Please note that LAStools is not "free" (see http://lastools.org/LICENSE.txt)
contact 'info@rapidlasso.de' to clarify licensing terms if needed.
ERROR: unknown file format. file name 'E:/DOUTORADO/ProbaLasA.tiff' must end in
*.bil *.asc *.flt *.dtm *.xyz *.img *.png *.jpg *.tif *.csv *.laz
GeographicTypeGeoKey: look-up for 4258 not implemented
GeogGeodeticDatumGeoKey: look-up for 6258 not implemented

Execution completed in 29.42 seconds

Results:

{'commands': ['C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Doutorado/LAStools\bin\blast2dem',
'-i',
'"E:\DOUTORADO\AnllonsLidar\PNOA_2015_GAL-W_498-4786_ORT-CLA-CIR.las"',
'-keep_class 2',
'-step',
'1.0',
'-hillshade',
'-o',
'"E:/DOUTORADO/ProbaLasA.tiff"']}

Another note I want to add is that some options in the Lastools like the proper blast2dem appear in Yellow in the QGIS process box. I tried to use those that appear in Green (Like Laz to Las) and it seems like it works.

Comment: It's your EPSG code not being recognized, have a read of https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/9IIRw5ZNCW4 with instructions on how to add new EPSG codes. What version of ASPRS LAS are these files in? If they're 1.4 the CRS **must** be WKT. It also doesn't like your file extension, use *TIF* and not *TIFF*.

Comment: Hi, Google Groups isn´t loading for me, can you provide a summary of the process? I confirm ASPRS are 1.4

Comment: Dear Munkund,

You can include new EPSG systems in the system ... you can added the system into the different CSV files included in \lastools\bin\serf\geo

Jorge is the relevant post.

Comment: Okay, I understood. I need to add 4258 & 6258 in the CSV files. They need to be added on all?

Comment: I think *ETRS89* (4258) and *European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble* (6258) should be included in gcs.csv. If the LAS was written to the ASPRS LAS specification 1.4 r13 the coordinate system has to be included as WKT, though GeoTIFF tags may also be present - if you run lasinfo on one of your LAS (or LAZ) files you should be able to see the WKT description which will have all the parameters needed, if not reference https://epsg.io/4258 and https://epsg.io/6258-datum to find the parameters. Though I've not done this before, all the CRSs' I use are already included.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I added both to my CSV and it didn´t work. Can I ask you,, but do you have a copy of your csv's that you could share where both EPSG's are already integrated?

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

> ERROR: unknown file format. file name 'E:/DOUTORADO/ProbaLasA.tiff'
> must end in *.bil *.asc *.flt *.dtm *.xyz *.img *.png *.jpg *.tif
> *.csv *.laz

The specified filename's extension is "tiff", which seems not among the recognized extensions.

Use the "tif" extension, instead.